# Python3 multiprocessing pool class gets stuck in join() method

Tags: python-3.8

Trying to run the code below. However I am unable to combine the result to one dictionary with join() method. It just keeps going indefinitely. Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if some library is not optimized for my MacBook silicon yet.

```
import random
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import math

start_time = time.time()
probs = {"cats":0.10,"dogs": 0.80, "bats": 0.10}

calculations = 10000
processors = 8

def f(how_many_times, times):
    for i in range(how_many_times):
        rand_num = random.random()
        total = 0
        for animal, prob in probs.items():
            total += prob
            if total > rand_num:
                times[animal] += 1
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    
    manager = mp.Manager()
    total_times = manager.dict()
    pool = mp.Pool(processors)
    calculations_per_processor = math.floor(calculations/processors)
    for i in range(processors):
        job = pool.apply_async(f, args=(calculations_per_processor, total_times))
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Code gives the following report after forcefully quitting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-890e4966932e> in <module>
     10 
     11     pool.close()
---> 12     pool.join()
     13 
     14     print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py in join(self)
    660         elif self._state not in (CLOSE, TERMINATE):
    661             raise ValueError("In unknown state")
--> 662         self._worker_handler.join()
    663         self._task_handler.join()
    664         self._result_handler.join()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py in join(self, timeout)
   1009 
   1010         if timeout is None:
-> 1011             self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
   1012         else:
   1013             # the behavior of a negative timeout isn't documented, but

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py in _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block, timeout)
   1025         if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
   1026             assert self._is_stopped
-> 1027         elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
   1028             lock.release()
   1029             self._stop()

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am not implementing the class "Pool" correctly. Basically I am trying to run function f() with all the processors available on my machine to minimize calculation time.

Comment: First off, welcome to the site! You put a lot of good effort into your post and I want to commend you for that! I don't have an answer off hand, but generally `join` and friends are particularly touchy like many things when dealing with concurrency. It's possible you may be running into deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only occurs in Jupyter notebook. I have no issue with join() method when running the code in terminal. Not sure how to fix notebook. I have tried to uninstall anaconda and reinstalling notebook with pip3. No success though